# How to get an HTML table from the document using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, perl, xpath, www-mechanize-firefox

I don't understand how to access an HTML table from a document.

I am playing with this link:
[Scotia Bank Jobs](http://jobs.scotiabank.com/search/advanced-search/ASCategory/IT/ASPostedDate/-1/ASCountry/Canada/ASState/Ontario/ASCity/Toronto/ASLocation/-1/ASCompanyName/-1/ASCustom1/-1/ASCustom2/-1/ASCustom3/-1/ASCustom4/-1/ASCustom5/-1/ASIsRadius/false/ASCityStateZipcode/-1/ASDistance/-1/ASLatitude/-1/ASLongitude/-1/ASDistanceType/-1)

The idea is to click on "Next page" button several times and gather all small HTML tables into one.

When I open the link with [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox), I can get the whole document (and first page HTML table) with

```
 my $cont= $mech->content( format => 'html' );
```

After that I click on "Next page" button with

```
my $id="search_result_next_page_link"; 
$mech->click({ xpath => qq{//*[\@id="$id"]}, synchronize => 0 });
```

I can click the button many times and the table is being changed inside the document, but I can not use  `$mech->content` any more, because the URL is the same and content is not changing.

I was trying something like :

```
my $tt= $mech->xpath('/html/body/form/div[4]/div/main/div/div[3]/section/div/div/table/text()');
print $tt;
```

but it prints "0".

I have a feeling that I am very close, any idea how to get HTML table after every click????

Comment: You could directly make the requests that clicking on the button is replicating -- if you look at them in the Inspector panel of your browser, they are simple `GET` requests with an incrementing page number, and the data returned is an HTML table.

Comment: @ialarmedalien  I am looking at the button in inspector and all I see is `Javascript:Paging($url, '2', 'True', 'False')`, where $url is the same URL of the page. '2' is the next page number here. But where to put it in URL for GET request? Can you, please, be more specific?

Comment: Reading the documentation, I can see that it's easy to get PNG screenshots of the page, but how to get the table's HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Finally....I had to bother the author of the `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` module and he provided with the solution how to get  the HTML code  of this table. Script should be something like this:

`@tt= $mech->selector('.tableSearchResults');
 $HTMLtable= $tt[0]->{innerHTML};`

Don't forget, you need to wait after every click (or create a cycle, waiting for the element to show up).